# Google Map Marker Clusters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

i've been trying to implement a new feature on one of my Google maps (MarkerClusterer), but i am not quite there yet.

It is running OK, but not smoothly and it would be great if you would look through the code and give me any tips/advice.

I am running a test here: (Link removed)

- Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing an awful lot within the loop that creates your markers.  For instance you should only need to do `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(...)` after that loop, not within every iteration of it!

Ok, here I've simply moved that line out of your loop.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < mapLocationsdata.businesses.length; i++) {
    var businesses = mapLocationsdata.businesses[i];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(businesses.lat, businesses.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        title: businesses.company,
        icon: placemarker[businesses.placemaker],
        clickable: true,
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    (function(i, marker){
        var infobox = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:
        //This creates the content inside the popup info window when clicked
            '<div class="info"><div class="info1"><h4>'
            +businesses.company+
            '</h4></div><div class="infotel">'
            +businesses.itemAdresse+businesses.itemPostBy+businesses.itemTlf+businesses.itemEmail+businesses.itemWeb+
            '</div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>',
        });

        //This function opens the info box and toggles the icon bounce
        marker.addListener('click',  function() {
          infobox.open(map, marker);
          toggleBounce(map, marker);
        });
        //This function stops the bouncs on the icon once the infowindow is closed
        infobox.addListener('closeclick', function() {
            toggleBounce(map, marker);
        });

        // POSSIBLY THIS FUNCTION COULD BE MOVED OUT OF THE LOOP TOO
        //This makes them bounce when clicked
        function toggleBounce() {
          if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
          } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
          }
        }
    })

//The marker loop generates all of the markers

    // NO IDEA WHAT THE POINT OF THIS LINE IS:
    (i, marker);    

//Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}


var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    gridSize: 60,
    minimumClusterSize: 2,
    calculator: function(markers, numStyles) {
       if (markers.length >= 50) return {text: markers.length, index: 3}; // red
       if (markers.length >= 5) return {text: markers.length, index: 2};  // yellow
       return {text: markers.length, index: 0};    }                      // blue
});
```

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for response. Any idea what changes i need to do, or have i just f**ked it up beyond fixing :)

Comment: Duncan...You are a lifesaver!
I'd been working on that for ages, trying everything, and then the fix was that easy (for you). Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome!  Feel free to ['accept'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) my answer